# Integrating Google Fonts into my Android app

Tags: java, android, fonts, google-font-api

Surprisingly difficult to get information about this. I've done a fairly exhaustive search. All I can come up with is the webfonts API.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/webfonts/v1

How would I add, say, all 600 fonts into my Android app? Apps such as Fontasy do this well: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.youthhr.fontasy&hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all Roboto fonts on [this site](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Roboto) where you can also download them (a .zip file containing several .ttf files).

Comment: I see. I guess I can just include them in my project and then do something like: ``Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myFont.ttf");
    TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    myTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);``